# How can I fix Prettier error and Parsing Error : No babel config file for

Tags: json, typescript, parsing, babeljs, prettier

When I'm using react there is no problem but if I'm using react native with tsx I have this problem. How can I fix these two errors. I tried some solutions but didn't work for me(changing the settings.json). And my **settings.json** file like this :

[image: settings.json file]

**Prettier error:**

[image: Prettier error]

**Parsing error:**

[image: Parsing error]